# How to save cGAN generated images in file directory

Tags: python, torch

```
import os
import torch
from torchvision.utils import save_image

sample_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/computer_vision/image_anotation/generated_mask'
if not os.path.exists(sample_dir):
  os.makedirs(sample_dir)
  if(epoch == n_epochs-1 ):
    fake_image_and_labels = 'fake_image_and_labels-{0:0=4d}.png'.format(i)
#save_image(fake, os.path.join(sample_dir, fake_fname), nrow=8)
save_image(fake[i], os.path.join(sample_dir, fake_image_and_labels), nrow=1)
```

```
import os
import torch
from torchvision.utils import save_image

sample_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/computer_vision/image_anotation/generated_mask'
if not os.path.exists(sample_dir):
  os.makedirs(sample_dir)
  if(epoch == n_epochs-1 ):
    fake_image_and_labels = 'fake_image_and_labels-{0:0=4d}.png'.format(i)
#save_image(fake, os.path.join(sample_dir, fake_fname), nrow=8)
save_image(fake[i], os.path.join(sample_dir, fake_image_and_labels), nrow=1)
```

how to save the generated images to a disk file individually. can you share your exercises

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have generated images using GAN  and at the end, I want to save the generated image to my disk file , for this I tried the above code but it does not save any image